# Django + REST_Framework - how can I get my app to POST serialized data to another HTTP server?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django app that is using REST_Framework and I can GET, POST, PUT, etc., to it as expected.

What I would like to do now, however, is automatically POST data from my Django app to another server.

Basically, I have a situation in which an asynchronous job runs, and when it is complete, rather than wait for the other server to poll my app for the latest updates, I want my app to just POST the data automatically.

I would like to continue using the REST_Framework serializers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) do post your data (towards the end of your view function).

```
payload = serialized_object
request.post(url, data=payload)
```